# How to get Team id where Teams bot is installed

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

In Microsoft Teams, how to retrieve team-ids where the bot is installed if the server missed the installation callback webhook?

I tried using the API `GET /v3/conversations?continuationToken={continuationToken}` mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0), but it gave HTTP 405

```
{
    "message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."
}
```

Comment: Something doesn't look right. In your first two samples, the "conversationType" is  "personal", which looks like you're adding the bot to personal scope in those examples. Are you -sure- you're adding it to a Team in those samples?

Comment: Hi @Gaurav Could you please confirm whether you are adding the bot scope for Team

Comment: @Ravindra-MSFT, Hilton Yes I was adding the bot to a team scope. I noticed that the bot was already installed in the team, thats why add to team callback didn't came. Is there a way to fetch list of teams where the bot is installed?

Comment: @GauravSharma  I am unable to reproduce this issue from our end and can you please share your manifest file and in your call backs [conversation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhNvn.png) is showing as personal and also could you explain how your adding bot. So that I can repro and come back with sol.

Comment: HI @GauravSharma are you able to resolve the issue. And fetch TeamId from TeamBot.

Comment: Hi @Ravindra-MSFT the issue for not receiving the callback was solved, but fetching the team ids after installation is still not possible it seems. I have therefore updated the question asking how to fetch the team-ids.

Comment: @Ravindra-MSFT I am also stuck on the same issue. I have also raised my issue at https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/issues/3953. Few quick questions here. How do I install the bot the team scope? Do I select add to team option? If yes, the team id I get here is the channel id in which bot is installed and not actual team id. The documentation is not at all clear in this case :(